# how to get the second word of an element in a list

Tags: python

Given an input string, search the list of tuples that store all the bus stop data and return a list of the tuples that contain roads with the matching string. UPPERCASE and lowercase are considered considered the same.
If no matches are found, return an empty list instead.

Assume that the bus stop data is already provided, i.e. that the following statement has been evaluated:

> bus_stops = read_data('bus_stops.txt')

I am given

> bus_stops.txt
> 01012,Victoria St,Hotel Grand Pacific
>
> 01013,Victoria St,St. Joseph's Ch
>
> 01019,Victoria St,Bras Basah Cplx

And when the following expression is executed:

> lookup_bus_stop_by_road_name(bus_stops, 'st')

I should get:

> [('01012', 'Victoria St', 'Hotel Grand Pacific'), ('01013', 'Victoria St', "St. Joseph's Ch"), ('01019', 'Victoria St', 'Bras Basah Cplx')]

Please help me check my code:

```
def lookup_bus_stop_by_road_name(bus_stops, name):

    matched = []

    for stops in bus_stops:
        new_name = name.lower()
        if stops[1] == new_name:
            matched.append(stops)
    return matched
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An even shorter (and Pythonic) way would be to use list comprehensions like that:

```
def lookup_bus_stop_by_road_name(bus_stops, name):
    return [bus_stop for bus_stop in bus_stops if name.lower() in bus_stop[1].lower()]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked, but can explain to me what the code does?

Comment: Actually, it is a condensed version of what you were trying to do using `for`, `if` and `append` keywords. It is called list comprehensions and is a powerful tool for Python programmers. See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

Replace `s` with `open` etc.. I've used `s` string to quickly demonstrate.

```
>>> s = '''\
01012,Victoria St,Hotel Grand Pacific
01013,Victoria St,St. Joseph's Ch
01019,Victoria St,Bras Basah Cplx''';
>>> 
>>> lines = s.split('\n');
>>> lines
['01012,Victoria St,Hotel Grand Pacific', "01013,Victoria St,St. Joseph's Ch", '01019,Victoria St,Bras Basah Cplx']
>>> l = [];
>>> for line in lines: l.append(tuple(line.split(',')));

>>> l
[('01012', 'Victoria St', 'Hotel Grand Pacific'), ('01013', 'Victoria St', "St. Joseph's Ch"), ('01019', 'Victoria St', 'Bras Basah Cplx')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your function to

```
def lookup_bus_stop_by_road_name(bus_stops, name):
    matched = []
    new_name = name.lower()

    for stops in bus_stops:
        if name in stops:
            matched.append(tuple(stops.split(',')))
    return matched
```

Comment: I've tried this before but it return me an empty list.

Comment: it should work. check the function arguments by printing them.