# Why does my loop rotate only once?

Tags: python, rotation

I'm supposed to write a function which gets a list and rotates it several times (number of rotation is given)

```
def rotate1(lst):

print(lst[-1:]+lst[:-1])

def rotatek_v1(lst,k):
    for i in range(0,k):
       rotate1(lst)
    print(lst)
```

for some reason, in the second function it rotates only once but I need it to rotate k times (I need it to run the function rotate1 k times), what should I fix?

Thanks

Comment: What arguments are you passing to the function call? It's working fine for me.

Comment: I tried the input [1,2,3,4,5] I'm supposed to get [4,5,1,2,3] but instead I get [5,1,2,3,4]

Comment: @user3369309 corrected indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the value back

```
def rotate1(lst):
  return lst[-1:]+lst[:-1] # here

def rotatek_v1(lst,k):
    for i in range(0,k):
       lst = rotate1(lst) # and here
    print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not modifying any value, you are just printing, so each time you iterate, you will get the same value. You have to use the `return` statement, so you can use the result and assign it to a variable, like:

```
def some_function():
    return 100

some_var = some_function()
```

Applying it to your case:

```
def rotate1(lst):
    return (lst[-1:] + lst[:-1])

def rotatek_v1(lst, k):
    for i in range(0, k):
        lst = rotate1(lst)
        print lst
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> rotatek_v1([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 6)
>>> [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
    [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct code should be this -

```
def rotate1(lst):
    print(lst[-1:]+lst[:-1]);

def rotatek_v1(lst,k):
    for i in range(0,k): rotate1(lst);
    print(lst);
```

Comment: I don't see the difference

Comment: If it were a formatting issue, he couldn't even test it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579158/how-to-get-the-second-word-of-an-element-in-a-list/22579229#22579229

Comment: you shouldn't do that. If people see that your answer is correct, they will upvote it.

Comment: Sir, they are not upvoting... please is it not correct that they are not upvoting. Thanks!?

Comment: What he said. Please don't beg for upvotes. All it does is make you look bad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to align print statement in first function in right way like this

`def rotate1(lst):
     print(lst[-1:]+lst[:-1])`

and in case of return then

`def rotate1(lst):
     return (lst[-1:]+lst[:-1])`